Set specific controller to require role in ASP.NET Core 8 new authentication and authorization
I use the new identity of ASP.NET Core 8:
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<IdentityUser>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DefaultDbContext>();

// ...

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapIdentityApi<IdentityUser>();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization();

but I don't find any documentation how to add roles to specific controller or route.

Please kindly check the official doc about Role-based authorization in ASP.NET Core.

When I put [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] it blocks the request even if it's user has Admin role, I assume it because I use the built in identity of asp net core 3

Hi @Tammar, could you create a brand new repo which can reproduce the issue for us? Maybe there are some issue in your project. And please hide sensitive information.

Suddenlly it works!!! don't know why...
Thank you very much!
